# Chrome not displaying website correctly

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having an issue with the Chrome browser - it doesn't display namecheap.com correctly (all the other websites I tried seem to work fine). Chrome on other computers I tried works fine. IE on the same computer also works fine with namecheap.com. I tried reinstalling Chrome to no avail. What could the be issue? I've updated Windows with all the latest updates.
[image]

Comment: What method are you installing Chrome? Are you using a download that you saved? Or are you installing from the website? If you are using a downloaded install, try downloading a new Chrome install from the website. One more thing to check, maybe you have a block from AdBlock installed on your Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop-down menu icon on the top right hand corner of your window suggests that your version of Chrome is not up to date. I would suggest updating Chrome to the latest version first and then trying to access the website again.

Another possible cause of the problem would be a slow internet connection.

Comment: Okay I got it to work, but don't know why. It was not due to Chrome out of date though. I turned off Kaspersky, navigated to the site and it worked. Turned Kaspersky back on and it's still working. Don't know why this solved the problem...